# Make the first character uppercase in python 3.4.1

Tags: python, string

I know that you can make a whole statement capital by using ".upper" but .upper() but how do you just make just the first word capital on input statement?

How would I make it in this case?

```
custumer_name = input(format("Enter Custumer's name: ",">27s"))
print (custumer_name)
```

What I would like to do is that, if I input "peter", it capitalizes the first letter "P" and then it prints it as "Peter".

Answer (score 6):

Short answer:

`str.capitalize()`

Use like this:

```
s = "peter".capitalize()
```

or

```
s = "peter"
s = s.capitalize()
```

Lots of other useful information in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#textseq)

Answer (score 3):

If you want just the first word capitalized, use `capitalize`. If you want all words capitalized (e.g. for a name written as Firstname Surname), use `title`:

```
>>> s = 'peter jones'
>>> s.capitalize()
'Peter jones'
>>> s.title()
'Peter Jones'
```